# Number of page views higher when looking at Landing pages compared to all pages

Tags: google-analytics

I have created two custom reports showing page views, one with 'Page' as the primary dimension, and the other with 'Landing Page'.

However, the number of page views for my home page under 'Landing Page' is more than under 'Page' (no segments applied). Any idea why this is so? Thanks!

['Page' custom report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fyn6M.jpg)

['Landing Page' custom report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGnP8.jpg)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because question is about Google Analytics the application and is not programing related.

Answer (score 0):

Its because they aren't measuring the same thing. 
If you have landing page as a dimension then the number of page views would refer to all page views for people who landed on the homepage.